# How to retrieve All information When I select a value

Tags: php, jquery

I have A question in php and jquery
When i Select Itemname All information From item name are display on a textbox..
How To do this with jquery?

Here is my codes..

**PHP**

```
$iname = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT itemname,quantity,critical_level FROM table_inventory");
    $iname->execute();
    $iname->bind_result($itemname);
    $iname->store_result();

    $itemnames = array();

    while($iname->fetch())
    {
      $itemnames[] = $itemname;
    }


<form>
<div class="form-group ">
<label for="group" class="control-label col-lg-2">Item Name</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<select id="quantity"  name="quantity" class="form-control">
<option disabled selected>Item Name</option>
<?php foreach ($itemnames as $i): ?>
<option><?=$i?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
<label for="group" class="control-label col-lg-2">Quantity</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<input class=" form-control" required="required" name="group" type="text"  id="output"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
<label for="group" class="control-label col-lg-2">Critical Level</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<input class=" form-control" required="required" name="group" type="text" />
</div>
</div>

</form
```

when I select from dropdown
All the information from i selected 
are output in
the textbox
THANKS IN ADVANCE..
SORRY FOR THIS NEWBIE QUESTION

Comment: You need something to bridge the Client (jQuery) and Server (PHP, mySQL) gap. That solution is AJAX. You can use an AJAX call with jQuery to send the original value to a PHP page and call the database. You can then insert the returned data to a textbox on your page

Comment: HI Thanks
Can You Give me
atleast A example
because I Have no idea how to do this..
TIA

Comment: I showed some code below in the answers, let me know if you need something explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example, say you have a bunch of different Makes of cars, and you want it to automatically update with the corresponding models

AJAX CODE that would go in your jQuery
Assuming Make is a dropdown and Model is a `<textarea id="model"></textarea>`

```
$("#make").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://yoursite.com/modelUpdate.php",
        data: {make: $(make).val()},
        type: "post",
        success: function(msg){
        $("#model").val(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

So when you change the make in the drop down the value of the make is sent up to modelUpdate.php

Here is some simple PHP code you would need in modelUpdate.php I am not going to write the query out for you but I will show you how to return the data.

```
$make = $_POST['make']; // This is the AJAX value that was selected on your page
//DO YOUR QUERY HERE TO GET THE DATA
echo $data;
```

Anything you echo on this PHP page will be returned and will set that `<textarea id="model"></textarea>` value.

I hope this gets you started in the right direction